# Sort array by custom variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

```
$("#show_times_available_" + pos).find("td span").parent().each(function(){ 
    array.push($(this).attr("id")); 
    array = array.sort();
});
```

My array takes all of the elements and grabs their ID and pushes it into an array so my array will end up as;

```
[ "mon_0600-0", "sun_0700-0", "thu_0600-0", "thu_0700-0", "tue_0300-0", "wed_0700-0" ];
```

What I'm trying to do is sort those elements as (mon, tue, wed, etc...) every time a new element is pushed into the array. so that my array will end up as;

```
[ "mon_0600-0", "tue_0300-0", "wed_0700-0", "thu_0600-0", "thu_0700-0", "sun_0700-0" ];
```

Using the basic `sort()` function will put it alphabetically and I know that the `sort()` function can take in another function. I'm just not sure how to set this up in vanilla javascript or jQuery. Is there a CASE THEN or a way to use `when()` and `then()` to sort these? I've search all around google and SO but nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you go with a custom sort function

```
// your array
array = [ "mon_0600-0", "sun_0700-0", "thu_0600-0", "thu_0700-0", "tue_0300-0", "wed_0700-0" ];

// the order stored in an object
daynames={
    mon:1,
    tue:2,
    wed:3,
    thu:4,
    fri:5,
    sat:6,
    sun:7
}

// the custom sort function which gets the value for the dayname-key and compares
function SortByDayName(a, b){

  // get the value of dayname + the time 
  var aName = daynames[a.substr(0,3)] + a.substr(4,7);;
  var bName = daynames[b.substr(0,3)] + b.substr(4,7);; 
  return ((aName < bName) ? -1 : ((aName > bName) ? 1 : 0));
}

// apply sort
array.sort(SortByDayName);

// output:
["mon_0600-0", "tue_0300-0", "wed_0700-0", "thu_0600-0", "thu_0700-0", "sun_0700-0"]
```

Comment: doesn't handle times, try switching `"thu_0700-0"` and `"thu_0600-0"`

Comment: oh i did not get this reqirement, that was an easy update, working now

Comment: now thu_0600 becomes `4060` and thu_0700 becomes `4070` so the comparison will put the correct order

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a custom function to [`sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) as you say. In here, you need to split the days from the times, then return the comparison of the day part then the time part (if the days are the same):

```js
var arr = ["mon_0600-0", "sun_0700-0", "thu_0600-0", "thu_0700-0", "tue_0300-0", "wed_0700-0"];

// store the order of the days
var days = ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun"];

var arrSorted = arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  // a and b are two times to compare

  // split each into days and times, e.g ["mon", "0600-0"]
  var aSplit = a.split("_");
  var bSplit = b.split("_");
  
  // get the index of the days to compare
  var dayA = days.indexOf(aSplit[0]);
  var dayB = days.indexOf(bSplit[0]);
  
  // if days are the same, compare the times using normal String comparison
  // if days are different, return the comparison of their position in the array
  return dayA == dayB ?
   aSplit[1].localeCompare(bSplit[1])
   : dayA - dayB;
});

console.log(arrSorted);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use [.sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) you can specify a function that does the comparison.

Your function must receive two parameters, like `compare(a,b)` and return less than zero if `a` comes first, zero, if both must occupy the same position, and greate than zero if `b` must be after `a`.

```js
var array = ["X123", "X0072", "X04"];

var compareFunction = function(a,b) {
  var _a = parseInt(a.substring(1));
  var _b = parseInt(b.substring(1));
  return _a-_b;
}

$('#original').text(JSON.stringify(array));

array.sort();
$('#sort').text(JSON.stringify(array));

array.sort(compareFunction);
$('#customSort').text(JSON.stringify(array));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p>Original:</p>
<pre id="original"></pre>

<p>Sort:</p>
<pre id="sort"></pre>

<p>Custom sort:</p>
<pre id="customSort"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use an array containing the days in a sorted way:

```
var days = ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun"];
```

then you can sort your data using indexes:

```
array = array.sort(function (x, y) {
    return days.indexOf(x.slice(0,3)) - days.indexOf(y.slice(0,3));
});
```

Comment: doesn't handle times, `"thu_0700-0"` and `"thu_0600-0"` are the wrong way round

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use this function to do that

```js
var array = ["mon_0600-0", "sun_0700-0", "thu_0600-0", "thu_0700-0", "tue_0300-0", "wed_0700-0"],
  sort = ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri", "sat", "sun"];

var sortondays = function() {
  var newArray = [];
  for (i = 0; i < sort.length; i++) {
    var t = sort[i];
    for (x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
      if (array[x].startsWith(t)) {
        newArray.push(array[x])
      }
    }
  }
  return newArray;
}
console.log(sortondays());
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem is perfect for [Sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map), because splitting and lookup for day is only once made for an element, and not for each sort callback.

```js
// the array to be sorted
var data = ["mon_0600-0", "sun_0700-0", "thu_0600-0", "thu_0700-0", "tue_0300-0", "wed_0700-0"];

// temporary array holds objects with position and sort-value
var mapped = data.map(function (el, i) {
    var value = el.split('_'), day;
    return {
        index: i,
        day: { mon: 1, tue: 2, wed: 3, thu: 4, fri: 5, sat: 6, sun: 7 }[value[0]] || 0,
        hour: value[1]
    };
})

// sorting the mapped array containing the reduced values
mapped.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a.day - b.day || a.hour.localeCompare(b.hour);
});

// container for the resulting order
var result = mapped.map(function (el) {
    return data[el.index];
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```